# Understanding dynamic allocation in ancient C

Tags: c, turbo-c++

You can consider it as an brain twister if your not that familiar with dynamic memory allocation.

First save this code as a C program in your bin directory.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct node {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
} *head=NULL;

void ins_at_beg()
{
    struct node *node=malloc(4);
    node->next=head; head=node;
    printf("Please enter the value to be inserted at the start: ");
    scanf("%d",node); // POINT A
}

void ins_at_end()
{
    struct node *node=head;
    while(node->next) node=node->next;
    node->next=malloc(4);
    printf("Please enter the value to be inserted at the end: ");
    scanf("%d",node->next->data); // POINT B
}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    ins_at_end();
    printf("%d",head->data);
    getch();
}
```

Execute this code and everything shall seem fine.

Now after the program gets executed `ins_at_end()` of the main function to `ins_at_beg()` and execute the program, things shall still seem fine.

Now **manually** undo the above change (change `ins_at_beg` to `ins_at_end`) and execute the program. Now you'll get the value of `head->data` as 0.

Now just change `node` of 'Point A' to `node->data` and you'll get to see that the entered value gets reflected on the screen (Note: We didn't call that function in the main function)

Now again reverse the above change and get 0 as the default value of `head->data`.

The main thing to notice here is that the output gets changed by a function which is just defined and is not called in the main function.

Just play with it for a while and you'll get to know what am I trying to say.

**Question:** Why does the program work as normal when I change `node` to `node->data` even if I am not practically calling the function I made the change in in the main function?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: This looks like a blog post, not a question.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear. Sorry for the inconvenience. Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: The first line of `ins_at_end` is setting `node` to `NULL`. I would expect it to crash on the next line, and indeed it does when compiled with gcc. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're hitting undefined behavior right off the bat because `head` is `NULL` when you do `struct node *node=head; while(node->next) ...`. You're also not allocating enough memory.

Comment: I have executed the program multiple times, so I wanted to know if there is any connection between them. I made some changes on `ins_at_beg()` and those changes altered the output of my program without being called in the main function. Are these lines being secretly executed? Is there something I am still not aware of? I am sure that undefined behavior doesn't get resolved by making changes in a function that is never going to be called.

Comment: If your question is about how some specific compiler is handling UB, your best bet would be to look at the generated assembly.

Comment: @JETM Please try replicating this code in standard C and let me know if it exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow because your code has undefined behavior it's not valid code and thus can't be 'standard C'.

Comment: The undefined behavior remains constant with irrespective of the number of times I execute it. Can I know what exactly is happening in the name of undefined behavior?

Comment: If your still viewing this thread, please note that **The question your viewing could not be deleted.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
scanf("%d",node);
```

And this:

```
scanf("%d",node->next->data);
```

Are incorrect.  The `%d` format specifier expects an `int *` as an argument.  But instead you're passing in a `struct node *` in one case and an `int` in the other case.  Using the wrong format specifier to `scanf` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is why you're seeing strange results.

You should be doing this:

```
scanf("%d",&node->data);
```

And this:

```
scanf("%d",&node->next->data);
```

Also, this makes assumptions about the size of a pointer:

```
struct node *node=malloc(4);
```

You should instead be doing:

```
struct node *node=malloc(sizeof(*node));
```

You've also got a problem here:

```
void ins_at_end()
{
    struct node *node=head;
    while(node->next) node=node->next;  //   <--- here
    node->next=malloc(4);
    printf("Please enter the value to be inserted at the end: ");
    scanf("%d",node->next->data); // POINT B
}
```

At program startup, `head` is NULL, so you're trying to dereference a NULL pointer which again causes undefined behavior.  Check for this situation before you do anything else.  Also, you should explicitly set the `next` pointer at the end of the list to NULL.

```
void ins_at_end()
{
    struct node *node=malloc(sizeof(*node));
    struct node *tmp;

    printf("Please enter the value to be inserted at the end: ");
    scanf("%d",&node->data);
    node->next = NULL;

    if (!head) {
        head = node;
    } else {
        tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next) tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the output vary even if I don't call the function I change in the main function?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow Undefined behavior.  You're writing to memory you shouldn't be when you use the wrong format specifier to `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&node->data);` makes no difference...As far as I have learned `->` operator is used instead of `.` dot operator when we refer to a entity by it's address.

Comment: Why does the program work normally when I change node to node->data even if I am not practically calling it in the main function.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow See my edit.  You're dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: If you have read this question so far then please ask a diamond moderator or the Community to delete this thread. Thank you.